# Redirecting to https with wildcard urls (htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following problem. I have a site where some pages must be redirected to the https-secured equivalent of the link.

I tried several things but in the end it seems that the server ends up in a loop redirecting :(

Now I redirect every page to the https page but that is not what I want to.

This is the code I use right now:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.domain.nl
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.nl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I would like to have al urls starting with bo- have https.

examples:

```
http://www.domain.nl/bo-users -> redirects to https://www.domain.nl/bo-users
http://www.domain.nl/bo-groups -> redirects to https://www.domain.nl/bo-groups
```

but

```
http://www.domain.nl/about-us -> stays at http://www.domain.nl/about-us
```

It is clear to me I need some wildcards in the rewrite condition for all urls startin with bo-.
We are using apache on the server.
Hope someone can send me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Frank

---

Update after the tips from Anubhava.

I current;y have this htaccess but I can't get it working (even when clearing the cache in my browser)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^bo- http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^bo- https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC,NE]


#rewrites een url to www. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$        http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$0 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hope for some extra help!
Thanks,
Frank

I just opened another call. The initial answer worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule:

```
# force HTTPS for bo- URIs
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^bo- https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC,NE]

# force HTTP for non bo- URIs
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^bo- http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I will test next weekend and let you know.

Comment: Finaly some time to get it done. Your solution works but I can't get it working to get back to non-ssl. I have to following code right now.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^bo- http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^bo- https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC,NE]

Hope you an help me again,

Thanks,

Frank

Comment: That appears right, I have also updated the same in my answer. Make sure you're testing in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, I tried again but can't figure out. I noticed that the rules are working when I have physical files. But I want to redirect every request to an index.php where the url will be processed and data is shown from the database. I noticed that when I am going to HTTPS the url in the index will be seen as /index.php/bo-test instead of /bo-test. Maybe you can help me again? I updated my htaccess in the original post.

Comment: That looks like a different requirement than what this question was all about. I would suggest opening a new question with the new requirement and close this Q&A by marking at as accepted.